# jQuery toggle only works on second click after scrollTo event

Tags: toggle, scrollto, jquery

I have some mobile navigation that uses a scrollTo function, that once clicked, makes my toggle function only work on the second click. It may have to do the the binding of the scrollTo click, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-bar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="nav-toggle">Menu</a>
</div>
<div class="section-wrap">
    <div id="section1" class="section">Section 1</div>
    <div id="section2" class="section">Section 2</div>
    <div id="section3" class="section">Section 3</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
    $('ul.nav a').removeClass('on');
    $(this).addClass('on');
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 30
    }, 200, function() {
        $('.nav-bar').removeClass('open');
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('a.nav-toggle').toggle(function() {
    $('.nav-bar').addClass('open');
}, function () {
    $('.nav-bar').removeClass('open');
});
```

See this for a working example of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/MhSKC/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your animate, you remove the `open` class. Then on the next click of the menu bar, the `toggle` function tries to remove the `open` class again, because that's the one of the two `toggle` functions that needs to execute next. Here's a slightly reworked solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/P4mtC/

```
$('a.nav-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.nav-bar').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: That worked, and I feel like an idiot. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
$('a.nav-toggle').toggle(function() {
    $('.nav-bar').addClass('open');
}, function () {
    $('.nav-bar').removeClass('open');
});
```

use

```
 $('a.nav-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.nav-bar').toggleClass('open');
});
```